# Coalesce() function on databricks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I want to replace null values from a column to 0 using coalesce() function instead of isNULL(). Can anyone tell me how ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `nvl` function instead (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/nvl.html)), like this:

```sql
select nvl(column, 0) as column from ...
```

Or coalesce itself (but for me nvl is more natural:

```sql
select coalesce(column, 0) as column from ...
```

Comment: You might want to read the link you shared. "This function is a synonym for coalesce(expr1, expr2).".